# Json to url with php

Tags: php, json

In my `$output` there is this:

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "network" : "BTC",
    "addresses" : [
      {
        "user_id" : 0,
        "address" : "3ABR5GohqyXzf2zebYwjmLuwV7vtFZw1BZ",
        "label" : "default",
        "available_balance" : "0.00000000",
        "pending_received_balance" : "0.00000000"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But now I want it to get to redirect like:
https://example.com/index.php?status=succes&network=BTC

etc. etc.

But `$output` can change to like:

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "network" : "BTC",
    "available_balance" : "0.00000000",
    "pending_received_balance" : "0.00000000"
  }
}
```

But then I still want it to work.
I don't know PHP enough for this, so I want to ask:

How to do this?

Comment: So, you want to get those values from that json and generate an url?

Comment: json_decode will turn it into an array for you. Then you just find the array elements with the keys that you need.

Comment: So you just want `status` and `network` from the possible JSONStrings right? And those 2 will always be there Right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want whatever it says, it gotta set in a url.

Comment: @ADyson It changes everytime, and I want all to get in the url..

Comment: @intapromotie I know. that's the point. Whatever is in $output, you can decode it and find the value each time you execute the code. Pretty much like MrCode's answer, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

Simply `json_decode()` and access the `status` and `network` properties:

```
$decoded = json_decode($output);
header('Location: https://example.com/index.php?status=' . urlencode($decoded->status) . '&network=' . urlencode($decoded->data->network));
exit();
```

Comment: @intapromotie in that case you did something wrong. 500 means internal server error. So switch PHP error reporting on (you can google how) and find out what the real error is.

Answer (score 0):

Get the data in the json as an array:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/index.php?status=' . $status;
foreach($data as $param->$value) {
    $url += '&' . $param . '=' . $value
}
header('Location:' $url);
```

Been a while since i've worked in php but this should handle a varying amount of parameters.

Comment: So, I must to add at $data my json. And what is $status?

Comment: Check the web server error log to see more details about the problem.